# How can I get a Covariance Matrix from Mean and Variance?

Tags: probability-distributions, matlab, correlation, covariance

this may be a very basic question.

I have the mean and variance for 12 lognormal distributions:

```
location    0.90109  0.59587  0.80460  0.65178  0.76307  0.52575  0.41322  0.30059         
scale 0.63551  0.65525  0.64227  0.65198  0.64503  0.65915  0.66496  0.67022
```

How can I determine the covariance matrix from this data which I can plugin into the code given below.

Basically, I am trying to create a sum of these distributions using the Fenton Wilkinson approximation.

Matlab code: http://www.snowelm.com/~t/doc/tips/20110902.en.html#fw

Actual paper: http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~pekkap/finsig03_pp.pdf

Any explanation is very appreciated.